# Hyperlink a field by extracting or selecting the leading 2 or 3 digit number from alphanum field

Tags: excel, hyperlink, lookup

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ5Yt.gif)**Screenshot of xls and image folder**

[image]

I have a folder containing 2 items: `INDEX.xlsx` and a folder called MAPS with 109 pdf's called `Fire_1.pdf` thru `Fire_109.pdf`.
 In the `INDEX.xlsx` are fields with street name and MAPPAGE (C2). A street can be found on more than one page. Therefore C2 can contain any of the following entries: (The map has 4 quadrants A-D, but that doesn't matter for this purpose)

`5A` shows the street is found on `5.pdf`
`27C` shows the street is found on `27.pdf`
`105A` shows the street is found on `105.pdf`
`5A`,`4B` shows most of the street is found on `5.pdf`
`104B`,`105A` shows most of the street is found on `104.pdf`

I'm hoping a formula can find only the **first number** 1-109 and fetch the pdf from the MAPS folder. *Afterthought- Would they be easier to select if I added hyphens?  `5-A, 27-C, 105-A?*`

```
MAPS\Fire_5.pdf  
MAPS\Fire_27.pdf  
MAPS\Fire_105.pdf  
MAPS\Fire_5.pdf  
MAPS\Fire_104.pdf
```

snippets and experiments include:
 This actually chooses the map number correctly

```
 =LOOKUP(99^99,--
 ("0"&MID(C2,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},C2&"0123456789")),ROW($1:$10000))))
```

Then I try to plug it in here in place of the Substitute clause

```
 =Hyperlink( ".\" & "MAPS" & "\" Substitute(C2," ", "") & ".pdf", C2)

 =HYPERLYNK(".\" & "MAPS" & LOOKUP(99^99,-
("0"&MID(C2,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},C2&"0123456789")),ROW($1:$10000)))) 
& ".pdf",C2)

=HYPERLYNK("W:\ArcMap_Projects_0713\FireBook\Maps\" & LOOKUP(1, -
MID(C2,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},C2&"0123456789")),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(C2
))))) &".pdf")
```

Comment: How about this. Just tested it and it seems to work: `=HYPERLINK("W:\ArcMap_Projects_0713\FireBook\Maps\Fire_" & LOOKUP(99^99,--("0"&MID(C2,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},C2&"0123456789")),ROW($1:$10000))))&".pdf")`

Comment: Thanks. If I use your formula on C2 containing 105A, I get the Circular ref error.  If I add the word MAP to the next cell and attempt to hyperlink MAP, I get the #NAME? error.  Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot write the formula inside of C2 itself. You need to write it in another cell. (I am not sure if you are actually doing this, but it seems like you may be). If that does not help, please edit your question with a screenshot of the data sheet. I will be able to assist much easier that way.

Comment: Thanks @ScottHoltzman  Picture added above. Below is the formula     =HYPERLINK("W:\ArcMap_Projects_0713\FireBook\Maps\PageName_" & LOOKUP(99^99,--("0"&MID(D2,MIN(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},D2&"0123456789")),RO‌​W($1:$10000))))&".pdf")

Comment: This worked for me: `=HYPERLINK("W:\ArcMap_Projects_0713\FireBook\Maps\PageName_" & LOOKUP(1, --MID(D2,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},D2&"0123456789")),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(D2
))))) &".pdf")`

Comment: This code returns PageName_1 for all pages beginning with '1', like '19' and '105'.  The code returns '#N/A' for everything else. I did edit the code for the subsequent records, 'D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6' See attached picture at top called 'result'. Thanks

Comment: are you open to using a custom UDF via VBA?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman solved it.  Comparing your Feb 12 code to yesterday's, I added a space before the last & causing your Feb 12 formula to work correctly for all number possibilities.  Thank you Scott.